# Python BeautifulSoup Extract specific URLs

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to get only specific URLs?

Like:

```
<a href="http://www.iwashere.com/washere.html">next</a>
<span class="class">...</span>
<a href="http://www.heelo.com/hello.html">next</a>
<span class="class">...</span>
<a href="http://www.iwashere.com/wasnot.html">next</a>
<span class="class">...</span>
```

Output should be only URLs from `http://www.iwashere.com/`

like, output URLs:

```
http://www.iwashere.com/washere.html
http://www.iwashere.com/wasnot.html
```

I did it by string logic. Is there any direct method using BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can match multiple aspects, including using a regular expression for the attribute value:

```
import re
soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('http://www\.iwashere\.com/'))
```

which matches (for your example):

```
[<a href="http://www.iwashere.com/washere.html">next</a>, <a href="http://www.iwashere.com/wasnot.html">next</a>]
```

so any `<a>` tag with a `href` attribute that has a value that starts with the string `http://www.iwashere.com/`.

You can loop over the results and pick out just the `href` attribute:

```
>>> for elem in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('http://www\.iwashere\.com/')):
...     print elem['href']
... 
http://www.iwashere.com/washere.html
http://www.iwashere.com/wasnot.html
```

To match all relative paths instead, use a negative look-ahead assertion that tests if the value does *not* start with a schem (e.g. `http:` or `mailto:`), or a double slash (`//hostname/path`); any such value *must* be a relative path instead:

```
soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'^(?!(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9+.-]*:|//))'))
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. For people who aren't aware of libraries. You need to 
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re`

Comment: I have one more question. We can perfectly extract links if they are in `http://www.iwashere.com/xyz...abc.html` format. But, if the links are local. Say, like `[<a href="washere.html">next</a>, <a href="wwasnot.html">next</a>]`. How can I extract the underlying link? When HTML code is seen, link is hyperlinked with proper location. Any way to extract such links?

Comment: @searcoding: You'd need to match anything that doesn't start with a scheme or double slash; any `href` value that does *not* start with those is a relative URL instead. Use `href=re.compile(r'^(?!(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9+.-]*:|//))')` (that's a negative look-ahead to test for a scheme or double slash, anything that has those does *not* match).

Answer (score 7):

If you're using [BeautifulSoup 4.0.0](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) or greater:

```
soup.select('a[href^="http://www.iwashere.com/"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with partial matching in [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho):

Input:

```py
html = """\
<a href="http://www.iwashere.com/washere.html">next</a>
<span class="class">...</span>
<a href="http://www.heelo.com/hello.html">next</a>
<span class="class">...</span>
<a href="http://www.iwashere.com/wasnot.html">next</a>
<span class="class">...</span>
"""
```

Code:

```py
from gazpacho import Soup

soup = Soup(html)
links = soup.find('a', {'href': "http://www.iwashere.com/"}, partial=True)
[link.attrs['href'] for link in links]
```

Which will output:

```py
# ['http://www.iwashere.com/washere.html', 'http://www.iwashere.com/wasnot.html']
```